# Powershell security get-service different results interactive vs scheduled-task

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-service

I've spent hours trying to pin down this problem.  I'm running a PowerShell to verify if various services are running.  I want to run it every 5 minutes from Windows Task Scheduler.

It checks services on other servers, and some on the same machine on which it is running. When I run it under task scheduler, under the same userid that I'm running interactive I get different results.  Interactively, shows all the services on local machine are running.  When run through task scheduler, it tells me that service is not found.

This is just a fragment of a larger program.  I get the server/service names from a CSV file, then at the end it sends a nice HTML email.  I added the Add-Content to create a trace file to prove this happening.

```
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $reportStatus = "" 
    $ServerCount = $ServerCount + 1  

    #$Service = (get-service -Name $line.ServiceName -ComputerName $line.ServerName)
    #this is slower than above, but it gives us the processId which we can use to find out what time the service/process started 
    write-host "Verifying: " $line.ServerName $line.ServiceName 
    $myDate = Get-Date
    Add-Content D:\scripts\ServiceMonitorTrace.txt "$myDate  $($line.ServerName) $($line.ServiceName)"
    $Service = (get-wmiobject win32_service -ComputerName $line.ServerName -filter "name = '$($line.ServiceName)'")
    if ($Service -eq $null) 
    {
        $reportStatus = "Service Not Found: name = '$($line.ServiceName)'"
        $trColor = "Yellow"
        $ErrorCount = $ErrorCount + 1  
        $CriticalErrorCount = $CriticalErrorCount + 1
        $CreationDate = "NA" 
        Write-Host "----> $reportStatus " 
        Add-Content D:\scripts\ServiceMonitorTrace.txt "$myDate  $reportStatus" 
    }
  }
```

New Simpler Version (has exact same issue): 
$Service = (get-wmiobject win32_service -ComputerName "DAL-BIZ-APP01" -filter "name = 'LanManServer'")
if ($Service -eq $null) 
{
  $reportStatus = "Service not found" 
}
else 
{
  $reportStatus = "Service found" 
}
$myDate = Get-Date
Write-Host $reportStatus
Add-Content D:\scripts\ServiceTestTrace.txt "$myDate  $reportStatus"

Interactive Results:

```
10/31/2013 09:34:00  DAL-BIZ-APP01 MSDTC
10/31/2013 09:34:00  DAL-BIZ-APP01 BTSSvc$BizTalkHost_QT_Default
```

Scheduled Job Results:

```
10/31/2013 09:25:42  DAL-BIZ-APP01 MSDTC
10/31/2013 09:25:42  Service Not Found: name = 'MSDTC'
10/31/2013 09:25:42  DAL-BIZ-APP01 BTSSvc$BizTalkHost_QT_Default
```

I run it from a command file that contains this:

```
powershell -command "& 'D:\Scripts\ServerMonitor.ps1'" d:\Scripts\ServerMonitorConfig.csv
```

Running the command file from a non-admin command prompt window or the scheduler also seems to have different results.

New Simpler Version if someone want to try, just substitute two computer names:

```
$Service = (get-wmiobject win32_service -ComputerName "DAL-BIZ-APP01" -filter "name = 'LanManServer'")
if ($Service -eq $null) 
{
  $reportStatus = "Service not found" 
}
else 
{
  $reportStatus = "Service found" 
}
$myDate = Get-Date
Write-Host $reportStatus
Add-Content D:\scripts\ServiceTestTrace.txt "$myDate  DAL-BIZ-APP01 $reportStatus" 

$Service = (get-wmiobject win32_service -ComputerName "DAL-BIZ-APP02" -filter "name = 'LanManServer'")
if ($Service -eq $null) 
{
  $reportStatus = "Service not found" 
}
else 
{
  $reportStatus = "Service found" 
}
$myDate = Get-Date
Write-Host $reportStatus
Add-Content D:\scripts\ServiceTestTrace.txt "$myDate  DAL-BIZ-APP02 $reportStatus"
```

Results:

```
10/31/2013 16:07:48  DAL-BIZ-APP01 Service found
10/31/2013 16:07:48  DAL-BIZ-APP02 Service found
10/31/2013 16:08:03  DAL-BIZ-APP01 Service not found
10/31/2013 16:08:03  DAL-BIZ-APP02 Service found
```

16:07:48 was from command prompt, 16:08:03 was from task scheduler.

Comment: When you run this interactively, are you running it in an elevated PowerShell window? I just checked and see that on my system, there is at least one service that shows up in an elevated console that is not listed in a standard console.

Comment: Also, if you're checking multiple servers, you should add the server name to your "Service Not Found" line - it should help you determine exactly where the problem is occurring.

Comment: The scheduler is running via a command file, I just now added that above in my question.  I can run the command file in a non-admin command prompt and it works fine.  I also want to emphasize that it works fine on the remote servers, it's only the local server that gets the "not running".  For the ultimate output, I send an HTML formatted email, so it is very easy to read. The above trace/output was just for quick debug.

Comment: Put new sample code in original post.

Comment: have you checked the box "Run with highest privileges" in the General tab of your task's proerties window? I am not sure this is the reason but I kind of solved a similar issue by checking the box

Comment: Yes, that box is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to code:

```
if ($error -ne $null) 
{
    Write-Host "----> $($error[0].Exception) " 
    Add-Content $TraceFilename "$myDate TRCE1 $($error[0].Exception)" 
}
```

Now I'm able to see the reason that was getting swallowed:

> 11/13/2013 11:35:37 TRCE1 System.Management.ManagementException:
>   **Access denied**     at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus
>   errorCode)    at
>   System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand.BeginProcessing()

I have not yet figured out the "Access Denied", but at least I'm happy I see the true error now, i.e. the reason the result of "get-wmiobject win32_service..." was null.

I'm following up with the "Access Denied" in a new thread here: 
[Access Denied - get-wmiobject win32_service (Powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961004/access-denied-get-wmiobject-win32-service-powershell)